# How to send an email using a template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm using this code in c# to send an email. I want this email to be based on a template. this email contains images and styles. I wanna change certain contents of the email( for example, names, links etc.). Any ideas how to go about it? The code is below,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


// Create outlook application object.
var outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

// Create mail message.
var newMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)outlookApplication.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
newMail.To = "example@exam.com";
newMail.Subject = "Example";
newMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "team@iny.co.uk";
newMail.Attachments.Add(@"c:\New\DebriefReportTemplate.docx");

newMail.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
newMail.HTMLBody = "<p>Dear Example,</p><p>Example example.</p>";
newMail.Display(true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Razor Engine is recommended to you, http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ . It is easy to use and the syntax is same as asp.net mvc 3 razor

Comment: Can i do that using Outlook Inteop library?

Comment: Yep, it will return a string that you can use to populate the HTMLBody property.

Answer (score 0):

> If Your keyword in the email template are fixed then you can us
>   Sting.Replace("Example","XYZ") and get your desired result

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `String.Format`

```
wMail.HTMLBody = string.Format("<p>Dear {0},</p><p>{1}</p>", name, message);
```

If you need something more complex, you should use a template engine like Castle Velocity or Razor as @allentranks suggested.

Comment: Thia can be used to modify existing outlook template file? if so, how?

Comment: Mmmmh I don't think so. You probably will want to add to the question the fact that the template you are talking about is an Outlook one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and xsl file with the formats and the labels.Pass the data to xsl and transform it to the html format.